Interpretation of the character Gabe in Fences?
From the Wikipedia page on August Wilson's Fences (whose text is available to read on the Internet Archive):

The brother Gabriel is potentially an allegory to salvation. Other than being actually named Gabriel, like the angel, Gabe wears a trumpet, constantly chases away unseen "hellhounds", and regularly believes himself to be speaking with Saint Peter. At the end, just before Troy's funeral, the family gathers around Gabe in the yard. He blows three times into his trumpet, but no sound comes out. In a moment of trance, Gabe begins to dance and sing. The sun breaks through the clouds while the family looks on. Troy is at last delivered and the rest of the family is too; each seeming to find peace in their relationship with Troy.  [citation needed] 

This paragraph doesn't seem to hold together very well: the second half of it is just a description of events in the play without explaining how they connect with any allegorical interpretation. It's also unclear what it actually means for a character to be "an allegory to salvation", and "potentially" is a bit of a weasel word.
What is the interpretation of the character Gabe? Does it really make sense to interpret him as representing salvation, or as connected to the archangel Gabriel?

I can see why that page says that. After all, Gabriel is the kind of person that Christianity is all about: "The meek shall inherit the earth". He is that. This Kennedy Center article about the themes in Wilson is pretty good. Like many of Wilson’s plays, Fences features stories and situations born out of folktales and oral tradition— tales that exist outside of the everyday world and can’t be easily explained. https://www.kennedy-center.org/education/resources-for-educators/classroom-resources/media-and-interactives/media/theater/august-wilson--fences/
